# How to print all interactions with a mock using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

So let's say I have to write some test on `ClassA` that has a `ClassB` as member and I'm mocking `ClassB`.

At the end of the test i would like to use `verify(..)` and `verifyNoMoreInteractions(..)` to set the behaviour and validation for all of the mock calls.

Let's say that the mock has more than 10 interactions with different methods.

Is there any way to get JUnit to print all of the mock interactions and then use it in the code?

Right now I'm just reading the code and looking for the calls and than writing the verification line in the test. I'm sure there is an easier way (TDD wont be possible in my situation :))

My use case: I have a class with an algorithm that uses a lot of other classes that I mock. While adding a new method that calls tons of other methods, I would like to make sure that only x amount of methods been called y amount of times as the code working now. This will make sure if someone changes something in the future, let's say by mistake calling a method 5 times instead of 4, then the test will fail.

Comment: What is your goal? What have your tried? Why do you need to print those interactions, how are you gonna "use it in the code"?

Comment: @Onheiron After getting all of the interactions with mock i can use verify(mock, times(x)).method(1); and after this the verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock) i would like to have the list of interactions in order to set the behavior of the methods

Comment: To use `verify(mock, times(x)).method(1);` you don't need the list of all interactions, that's what mockito does: it checks the interactions with mock.method(1) were x and no more/less.

Comment: @Onheiron yeah, i know this trick by in case you have class with 7-10 other mocks that each one has 10-20 interactions, i would like to have the list of interactions in advance and than write all of the verification instead write one, run, fix and so on..

Comment: The number of interactions expected should be given by the behaviour you're testing. I mean, you don't start from a list of interactions and then write verification (whatever that means), instead, you start by a desired behaviour (a set of desired interactions) and you check those occurred afterwards.

Comment: @Onheiron :) this would be solved by using TDD but that was not my intention. The given is that i have a class with an algorithm that use a lot of other classes that i mock, while adding a new method that calls tons of other methods, i would like to make sure that only x amount of methods been called y amount of times as the code working now, and make sure if someone will change something in the feature lets say by mistake calling another method and now its been called 5 times instead of 4, that the test will failed, therefore i would like to know the number of the current interaction

Comment: TDD is making a test before even writing any code (defining its behaviour before its implementation) and then code till the test passes. In this case, you don't want to do this, but you still have to want to test something. You test a behaviour, this means you want to test that, when you call method `a()` on your tested class, then methods `x()`, `y()` and `z()` are called on a given mock. Do you have access to the code of your tested class? If so, you should be able to know what interactions with each mock should be called when you call method `a()` just by reading it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [MockingDetails](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.22/org/mockito/MockingDetails.html) and either `printInvocations` or `getInvocations` to inspect the interactions belonging to a mock. However, this will not produce a list of invocations belonging to multiple mocks in the order that happened: just interactions with each individual mock.

Code snippet, as contributed by [elhefe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643675/elhefe) and [Anand Rockzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234110/anand-rockzz):

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockingDetails;

System.out.println(mockingDetails(mock).printInvocations());
/* or */
System.out.println(mockingDetails(mock).getInvocations());
```

Acknowledging your reluctance and caveats in the comments, I would say that this is a technique that does more to *lock in your current implementation* than to *analyze your real constraints and prevent regressions*. Furthermore, if your algorithm has a lot of interactions with direct collaborators, that might be an indication that the algorithm should be refactored.

If the system is untested or undocumented legacy code, this might be a practical way to programmatically generate a regression test or analysis--a *temporary starting point* for more-informed regression testing--but in your shoes I would instead start by documenting the contract of each component and then writing a test that confirms those interactions and constraints. As described in [the article "is there a difference between asking and telling?"](https://szczepiq.wordpress.com/2008/04/26/asking-and-telling/) by Mockito's original developer  Szczepan Faber), Mockito recommendations tend toward adding stubs until tests pass and adding verifications/counts only where there are expensive or non-idempotent side effects.

Comment: Because I have to re-figure this out everytime I come back to this comment:     `import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockingDetails;     System.out.println(mockingDetails(mock).printInvocations());`

Comment: `import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockingDetails; System.out.println(mockingDetails(mock).getInvocations());`